# AttributeError: str has no attribute name - django python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to read image from url and save into db.

```
image = Image()
name = urlparse(imgurl).path.split('/')[-1]
image.bild.save(name, File(urllib2.urlopen(imgurl).read()), save=False)#error line
image.von_location = location
image.save()
```

this is my Image model

```
class Image(models.Model):
   von_location= models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name="locations_image",default=0)
   bild = models.ImageField(upload_to=locationimage,default='')
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.bild.name
```

the error below is coming when i try to call the `save()` method of image file.

```
AttributeError: str has no attribute name
```

`name` is just a name of image as i read this here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/

this is the screenshot of error message

[image]

Comment: what does `return self.bild` return ?

Comment: @karthikr, self.bild.name returns the name of image file, this is what i thought

Comment: Can you try `image.bild.save(name, File(urllib2.urlopen(imgurl)), save=False)`?  urllib2.urlopen is supposed to return a file-like object already.  Also, the stack trace seems to have different variable names than the listed code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error on Django 1.4 with the test app below.  Basically, you'll need to use a `ContentFile` instead of a `File` since you are reading the contents of the image.  If you try to pass the file object directly to `File`, you'll run into an unknown size error.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FieldFile.save

Basic test app:

models.py

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="test")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

tests.py

```
import os.path
import urllib2
from urlparse import urlparse

from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

from testapp.models import TestModel

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_models(self):
        test_model = TestModel()
        imgurl = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico'
        name = urlparse(imgurl).path.split('/')[-1]
        content =  urllib2.urlopen(imgurl).read()
        #test_model.file.save(name, File(content), save=False) # error line
        test_model.file.save(name, ContentFile(content), save=False)
        test_model.save()
        print test_model
```

Comment: thanks, but ContentFile takes strings only i thought?

Comment: Images are stored correctly in the test.  I believe based on the headers present in the request for `urlopen` it'll try to decode it appropriately.  In this case for an image, it'll be a byte string, which then is handled appropriately by `ContentFile` as it uses a `StringIO` to rebuild the file object from a byte string.